# Find nearest time difference between logins

Tags: sql, date

I have a database of ID's and dates.
like so:

```
ID       Date
1        2019-12-1
1        2019-10-1
1        2019-09-1
2        2019-12-1
2        2019-10-1
3        2019-12-1
```

I want to write a query that will return the minimal difference between 2 dates for the same ID like so (Lets say in months):

```
ID       Difference
1            1
2            2
```

3 should not appear in the results at all as it has no repeat entry or appear a 3-NULL

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Do a self join, group by. min.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Define minimal difference. Months or days?

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions and aggregation:

```
select id, min(datediff(date, lag_date)) diff
from (select id, date, lag(date) over(partition by id oder by date) lag_date from mytable) t
group by id
```

The inner query retrieves the previous `date` for the same `id`. The outer query aggregates by `id` and computes the minimum date difference.

Note that date functions are highly database-dependent, so the syntax to compute the difference between dates does vary across database - the above solution uses MySQL syntax, other databases have alternative syntax that implement the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have tested this in oracle.

```
select A.id,min(MONTHS_BETWEEN(A.date1,B.date1)) from test A join test B on
A.id=B.id and A.date1>B.date1
group by A.id
order by A.id;
```

You can also use DATEDIFF to extract difference in months if you are using MySQL or SQL Server.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!